# Aptana Studio CreateJS Code Assist(Auto Complete)

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana, createjs

I've recently installed the [Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.org/) (I believe 3.4.1) and wanted to start to use [CreateJS](http://createjs.com/#!/CreateJS). When I start coding, I don't see any code assist or autocomplete for the CreateJS libraries.

Is this something I have to manually add? If so, how?

Or does Aptana Studio 3 just not support this? (What IDE does?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like Aptana supports Code Assist for the "Createjs" libraries. If you go to "Commands" > "Bundle Developement" > "Install Bundle" you will see a list of libraries which Aptana does support. As far as I know, Jquery is one of the Javascript based libraries which enjoy support in Aptana.